# I have seen some extra tag in chrome

Tags: html

I have seen some extra tag 'a' in chrome when I've pushed ctr+shift+j
this is my code

```
<heade>
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>titel</h1>
            <span id="btnNav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">ایتم 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>  ایتم 2</a>
                    <ul class="subMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 1<a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 2<a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 3<a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 4<a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">ایتم 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ایتم 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

this code I see in google chrome there is extra 'a' tag in this code. what is this?

```
<header>
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>titel</h1>
                <span id="btnNav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">ایتم 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>  ایتم 2</a>
                        <ul class="subMenu">
                            <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 1</a><a></a></li><a>
                            </a><li><a></a><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 2</a><a></a></li><a>
                            </a><li><a></a><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 3</a><a></a></li><a>
                            </a><li><a></a><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 4</a><a></a></li><a>
                        </a></ul><a>
                    </a></li><a>
                    </a><li><a></a><a href="">ایتم 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ایتم 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Jquery code

> $('.menu li').hover(function() {        if ($(this).find('.subMenu')) {
>             $(this).find('.subMenu').slideToggle('slow');       }   }, function() {
>         if ($(this).find('.subMenu')) {
>             $(this).find('.subMenu').slideToggle('slow');       }   });

Comment: do you have an extension that is injecting code?

Comment: You have syntax error. You should close the <a> tag  here:<ul class="subMenu">
                      <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 1<a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 2<a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 3<a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 4<a></li>
                     </ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing your `a` tags. You have:

```
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 1<a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 2<a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 3<a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 4<a></li>
```

It should be:

```
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ایتم 2 . 4</a></li>
```

Notice the ending tag has a `/`.